# Rails 3: Validating Model uniqueness of Time within a Time Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, time, model

My model has start_time:time and end_time:time fields. What I want to be able to do is to check that the start_time to end_time range of my particular Reservation model does not overlap with any other reservations.

So if there's a reservation from 4-6pm on Wednesday the 2nd, there can't be another reservation anytime from 4-6pm. How would I go about doing this? I'm not particularly sure as to how to validate Time ranges against other start_time,end_time tuples from the other Reservation entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this, perhaps:

```
def intersects?(reservation)
  to = reservation.end_time
  from = reservation.start_time
  Reservation.where('start_time > ? OR end_time < ?', to, from).count > 0
end
```

Comment: This does not work on reservation between dates in past and future.

Comment: I think it does. Can you provide an example?

Comment: If you have a reservations from 12:00 - 13:00 and one from 15:00 - 16:00 and want to reserve 14:00 - 15:00 Reservation.where('start_time > 14:00 OR end_time < 15:00') will count.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to return all reservations that intersect with the given one? Because in the scenario you provided my solution would not return any results (count == 0, so intersects? would return false), which should be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `validates` for this specific of a need, and just make something more like

```
before_save :time_check

def time_check
   if #time in range
      #reject
   else
      #accept!
end
```

or something like that, do you need help with the actual time checking?
Just remember you can add seconds to a time object `Time.now + (60*60)*hours` to get a range with `< and > tests`

Comment: I'm just not sure how to check my times against the times in the other entries. By that I mean, if I have an entry that has start x and end y, how do I know what those x and y are? Basically, how do I write my method to check against all entries in my Reservation table?